# Why does zsh =() syntax works with user input while <() doesn't

Tags: zsh, process-substitution

I'm running a command prompting user input from `stdin` and writing `export FOO=bar` to export some variables in user shell session via `source`. A simple Python implementation would be:

```py
# myprog.py
val = input()
print("export FOO='" + val + "'")
```

And my command:

```bash
source <(python myprog.py)
```

This works in `bash` but not `zsh`. For some reason, `stdin` with `<()` process substitution breaks in `zsh`: input is not passed to process and `CTRL+C` / `CTRL+D` just prints control character like `^C` on my terminal without effect (process is not killed). I have to kill the process some other way.

However `=()` syntax works with `zsh`:

```bash
source =(python myprog.py)
```

I understand that `<()` behave differently between `bash` and `zsh`, and [`zsh`-specific `=()` syntax](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) changes sub-process gets *written* (pipe vs. temporary file)... But why does `stdin` breaks so badly with `zsh`+ `<()` ? I can't find anything related to `zsh`'s `stdin` behavior in process substitution.

(For context, the "real" program is [`novops`](https://github.com/PierreBeucher/novops): it loads environment variables in current user shell via `source <(novops load)`, prompting user via `stdin` for an environment to use)

**EDIT:** Easier way to reproduce by simply reading and outputting with plain commands

```
# works with bash
# not with zsh
cat <(read foo && echo $foo)

# works with zsh
cat =(read foo && echo $foo)
```

Also possible to reproduce with container: `docker run -it zshusers/zsh:5.9`

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash]??

Comment: Because it touches a difference between bash and zsh

Comment: I think this could be titled **why did syntax <(...) break, when `=(...)` work in zsh**. But as this work under bash, the *problem* is a `zsh` concern.

Comment: Make your tries: `cat =(seq 1 5)`, for sample!

Comment: Hmm right, problem is indeed more about `zsh`. I updated title and changed tags. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Try this: `echo >test.sh $'#!/bin/sh\n\ntdir=$(mktemp -d)\nmkfifo "$tdir/fifo"\nset >"$tdir/envBefore"\npython myprog.py >"$tdir/fifo" &\n. "$tdir/fifo"\nset | diff "$tdir/envBefore" - | grep \'^[>+] \'\nrm "$tdir/fifo" "$tdir/envBefore"\nrmdir "$tdir"'`, then you could try: `bash test.sh`, `zsh test.sh`, `busybox sh test.sh`, `dash test.sh` and so on...

Comment: Is `novops load` outputting dotenv-compatiable syntax? Be aware there are subtle differences between dotenv and shell semantics, and in general you should *not* be sourcing dotenv files as if they were shell scripts.

Comment: Also, this problem could be sidestepped by `novops load` taking an environment name as an argument instead of having to prompt the user. I assume the name is not sensitive, so you could simply read that using ordinary shell channels, then passing it to `novops load` non-interactively: `read '?Environment name: ' env_name; source <(novops load "$env_name")`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub ah indeed I should test with multiple sh* variants. @chepner `novops load` output `export ...` suitable for source, with escape of special characters. What's the risk exactly? Can you provide example? Indeed it's possible to us `novops load -e ENV` but that's not so practical :)

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. For me, bash and zsh both process the `<(...)` in the same way (zsh version 5.8.1 and bash version 5.2.15). The only possible difference in your case could be that `python` in your bash environment means something differnt than in your zsh environment. Do a `type python` in both, to check.

Comment: It's not just a Python problem, but an input/stdin problem with process substitution. I edited with ways to reproduce the issue with plain zsh and containers.